# Variable label position in ggplot line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame summary created with `dplyr`

```
structure(list(maxrep = c(7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 
24L, 26L, 26L), div = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Premier Division", 
"Second Division"), class = "factor"), freq = c(1L, 10L, 4L, 
39L, 26L, 89L, 73L, 146L, 107L, 162L, 117L, 133L, 121L, 125L, 
116L, 91L, 110L, 65L, 95L, 43L, 75L, 38L, 43L, 24L, 38L, 16L, 
36L, 5L, 15L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("maxrep", 
"div", "freq"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -38L))
```

My intention is to use `ggplot2` to plot line graphs of 2 lines with different colour with text labels for each value.

What I did was

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=maxrep, y=freq, colour=div)) +
geom_line() +
geom_text(aes(label=freq), vjust=-.5)
```

The result was

[image]

**Now my question:** All the labels in the chart are above the points in respective lines. I want to have the labels for the different colours to be in different relative position, e.g. labels for cyan above the line, and labels for red below the line (i.e. variable `vjust`). Is there a way to do that?

Also, is there a way to get read of the letter `a` in the colour legend on the right?

Comment: Have you though on plotting each line at time altering hjust and vjust for each?

Comment: Not really; can't really figure out splitting the `geom_text` into two, one for each line?

Comment: Well, I thing @RStudent just implemented my suggestion idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new variable in the data.frame holding the `vjust` adjustment parameter:

```
df$pos <- c(2, -2)[(df$div == "Premier Division")+1]
```

And you could call `vjust` inside `aes` with the new `pos` vector:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=maxrep, y=freq, colour=div)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_text(aes(label=freq, vjust=pos))
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks, this is great, I managed to adopt it for even more conditions.

I actually tried this before I asked the question, but I didn't realise the `vjust` portion needs to be inside the `aes`.

Answer (score 5):

What about plotting the lines separately wich differing `vjust` values? You can get rid of `a` in the legend setting `show_guide = FALSE`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=maxrep, y=freq, colour=div, label = freq)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_text(data = df[df$div == "Second Division",], vjust=2, show_guide = FALSE) + geom_text(data = df[df$div == "Premier Division",], vjust=-2, show_guide = FALSE)
```

Which returns:

[image]