# labelling values using autoplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a time series model using package `forecast` and have plotted the observations *and* forecast values using `autoplot`.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(forecast)
y <- hw(AirPassengers, h=10, seasonal="multiplicative")
autoplot(y, main="Air passengers - Holt seasonal") +
  autolayer(y, series="multiplicative", PI=FALSE)
```

[image: Time series with future forecast values]

However, I am looking to label the observations like so:
[Variable label position in ggplot line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253587/variable-label-position-in-ggplot-line-chart) but only for the forecast values. I understand the clause ought to be `geom_text( aes(label = ?) )` but since the object `y` being passed onto `autoplot` is a `ts` I am unsure as to how to reference `?`

I have resorted to `as.numeric(y[["mean"]])` but got the error `Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y` since this is a vector and dates are missing?

Thank you.

Comment: You find the values here: `ggplot_build(p)$data[[4]]$y` where `p` is your plot. Pass `ggplot_build(p)$data` to the `data` argument in `geom_text()`

Comment: p + geom_text( aes(x,y, label=y), data=ggplot_build(p)$data[[3]] )
The above worked. Thank you for pointing me to right direction @markus